# Extracting headers from jpg data in php

Tags: php, xcode

I am trying to display the image noted in a MySQL database and I am working through the php docs. I have this so far:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM observationPhotos";
$result = mysql_query($select);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$imageData = $row['obsPhotoData'];

echo "Photo:<br />\n";
$exif = exif_read_data($imageData, 0, true);
echo $exif===false ? "No header data found.<br />\n" : "Image contains headers<br />\n";

  foreach ($exif as $key => $section) 
  {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) 
    {
      echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
    }
  }

}
```

My database holds one record. When running this I get the echo

> Image contains headers

but no more. Can anyone point out what I need to do to extract the headers correctly? I can get the image to display but no headers.

Detail of how the image is sent to MySQL from Xcode:

```
UIImage *image = [photos objectAtIndex:i]; // I have an array of photos NSData
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 10);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoPostString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", photoID] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

Comment: Does `$row['obsPhotoData']` contain the content of the image itself, or the filename? Note that [`exif_read_data()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) should accept filename. (and on a sidenote, mind that the mysql_* extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. You can find more information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated))

Comment: I am just getting my head around all this - the first time I have done it. I use Xcode to send the 'data' and I am assuming it is the headers and the image. See edited question.